# getUserMedia() error on Chromium - WebRTC on RPi?

Tags: chromium

I'm trying to get WebRTC to work on my Rapsberry Pi, and I'm getting an error that says that getUserMedia() isn't a supported function.

Is the Chromium browser that's been ported to the Pi capable of running WebRTC?

I updated to to latest version of Chromium, went to about://flags to enable all of the features needed, then I went to this site to test it (which gave me the error): https://apprtc.appspot.com/

What's the status of WebRTC in the current Chromium build?

Comment: it seems HTML5 video is not supported, why I can't yet say...